# What tool to use to implement a notification logger for android?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to make an app that will log all notifications when they are posted beginning from the time the app is started up. I tried to use the "NotificationListenerService" after reading other similar questions here. But the issue is that "NotificationListenerService" requires the "BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" permission which Android Studio tells me is "only granted to system apps". My app will not be a system app and I have seen other non-system apps from the Play Store achieve this feature. Such apps can be found by searching "Notification Log" on the Play Store and they function just fine without being system apps. What tool should I use to log notifications that will work without being system apps.

Comment: https://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/05/android-read-status-bar-notification.html check it, it may help you

Comment: That still uses NotificationListenerService and system only permissions. I already found it referenced in another question. Just to be sure I tried to compile it but it doesn't.